# Testing of deelevate code

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm working on an installer project which requires user rights only. 
While it works as designed, the LocalAppData folder is being detected correctly. But somehow some users manage to elevate the installer rights to the admin level, 
where the folder starts being found incorrectly as well as HKEY_CURRENT_USER, so the program stops working (it is my proposal).

So, now I have to reproduce the problem on my own. I know 3 ways of giving the administrator rights for a program:

- Right mouse clicking on the program/shortcut and selecting "Run as administrator";
- Running the program from cmd: runas /user: installer.exe;
- Creating another program with administrator rights manifest within and running the 
  installer from that program.

I've tried them all, but to no avail: it works as expected.

What I'm missing? How to reproduce the problem?

update clarification:  I need to test code that do deelevate

update 2: here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later.aspx
is good illustration of code I want to test

update 3: some intersting API http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/2008/09/23/why-createprocesswithtokenw-may-fail/

Comment: 4) Naming your application with `install` or `setup` in the name, which can cause auto-elevation under some versions of Windows. (Windows automatically elevates applications that appear to be installers and prompts for credentials/permissions when they are run.)

Comment: 5) create a UAC manifest that sets `requestedExecutionLevel` to `requiresAdministrator` and save it in a `appname.exe.manifest` file in the same folder as `appname.exe`.

Comment: You should fix your installer so that it works when the user has admin rights.